# Initiate ArrayList of dynamic type

Tags: java, list, serialization, gson, deserialization

I have an HTTP request handler that returns deserialized JSON an `Object`, which is derived from an abstract `Request` and then cast to the correct class. I'm having some issues making this handler return a `List` though.

```
public class ListMyResource extends AbstractRequest
{

    public boolean isCollection;

    public ListTransactions()
    {
        this.isCollection = true;
    }

    public final RequestMethod REQUEST_METHOD = RequestMethod.GET;

    public final String URL_METHOD = "";

    public Class<ArrayList<MyResource>> getResourceClass()
    {
        return new ArrayList<MyResource>().getClass();
    }
}

public Object getDeserializedResponse()
{
    Response response = new Response(this.request, true);

    try
    {
        if (this.request.isCollection())
        {
            List<this.request.getResourceClass()> list = new ArrayList<this.request.getResourceClass()>();
            listType = new TypeToken<ArrayList<AbstractObject>>() { }.getType();

            response.setData(deserialize.fromJson(this.getResponse(), listType));
        }
        else
        {
            response.setData(deserialize.fromJson(this.getResponse(), this.request.getClazz()));
        }
    }
    catch (JsonSyntaxException jse)
    {
        MyLibrary.LOG.error("Could not parse JSON", jse);
        response.setRequestWasSuccessfull(false);
    }

    return response;
}
```

The above code works fine if `isCollection()` returns false and the method only has to come up with a single deserialized object, but it doesn't work for collections as I can't put the result from `getResourceClass()` in the `<>` from the List. That results in `Identifier expected`. How can I approach this so I achieve the desired result?

Comment: Explain yourself clearly. When you say "It doesn't work", we don't know what you mean.

Comment: @Kayaman I changed the wording. Basically I want an alternative for `ArrayList<this.request.getResourceClass()>` as that does not compile.

Comment: You can't set a run-time base type for a generic collection. At run time, there is no base type. You need to tell Gson what type to deserialize into, but you need to know this at compile time to give the list the proper type.

Comment: Shouldn't this work just by passing `ArrayList.class` instead of `listType` to `fromJson()`? You can't create a typed `ArrayList` at runtime, since the generics only exist during compile-time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> `ArrayList<this.request.getResourceClass()>`

This cannot work. Java type parameters must be compile-time "constants" (I mean, something known to the compiler). So,

```
List<String> strings
```

is a valid syntax for the type parameters, but

```
List<some.runtime.expression.here()>
```

is not. Next thing, I would strongly recommend you not to use `Class<?>` to pass data type information. Note that `Class<?>` holds information about a *real* type in your system. Consider you want to have a list of strings, a list of integers and a list of booleans types. You can't do `ArrayList<String>.class` -- it's an illegal expression in Java, because actual type parameters are not a part of class information. Can you subclass `ArrayList` with something like `extends ArrayList<String>` and so on? You can but you shouldn't. What if the class to subclass is `final` or you're going to use `LinkedList`? Some sort of code bloat, isn't it?

`Class` is `java.lang.reflect.Type`, and Gson requires an instance of the latter to be passed to the `fromJson()` method. What if you construct it yourself? Gson provides a convenient mechanism to construct `java.lang.reflect.Type` and `java.lang.reflect.ParameterizedType` (the latter is used for collections very intensively in Gson by the way, see more for Gson [TypeToken](https://google.github.io/gson/apidocs/com/google/gson/reflect/TypeToken.html)s). The are two ways:

- `TypeToken.getParameterized(rawType, typeParameter1, typeParameter2)`

For example, `TypeToken.getParameterized(List.class, String.class).getType()` will return a `ParameterizedType` instance as if it you could write `List<String>.class`. This is a truly dynamic approach, and you can pass some runtime execution results to the `getParameterized()` method.

- `TypeToken` subclassing

The trick here is that `TypeToken` is an abstract class and it can be parameterized, letting Gson analyze a usually anonymous class for the actual parameters at runtime and let the `getType()` method return a compile-time composed type: `new TypeToken<List<String>>(){}.getType()` (subclasses can store information about their super classes parameterization, and Gson uses it at runtime). Note that `getRawType` returns `List.class` only - this is all just how Java generics are implemented since `Class` cannot store actual type parameters (read more for [Java generics and erasure](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generics_in_Java#Problems_with_type_erasure)).

Having this vague explanation in mind, just refactor your `getDeserializedResponse()` method making a request return `java.lang.reflect.Type` rather than `Class<?>`. I even think that you can remove `isCollection` from that method and just let Gson do it all itself: Gson *can* distinguish between `List<String>` and `List<Integer>` types.

Comment: Hi! You seem truly genius ;) This answer thought me a lot of things about Java's internals so thank you very much. I will be using the TypeTokens for my implementation.

Comment: @RoemerBakker One more note: type tokens are purely Gson entities. Usually your code should be platform- and library-agnostic as much as possible to preserve loose coupling. So a standard class `Type` would be really enough (note the `Gson.fromJson` method overloads - none uses type tokens). But, and it's true, Gson type tokens give a more conventient mechanism because of being type-parameterized and having a nice `<T>`, and using `Type` disables compile-time type cast checking unfortunately and requires higher accuracy. But anyway, it's all up to you.